# Hiding an environment but keeping equation labels and their numbers inside

Tags: amsmath, environments, labels

I want to hide some of the proofs of some lecture notes that are given to students. I defined a new proof environment `hiddenproof` because I want to only hide some of the proofs. I can then hide this environment (actually I'm replacing its content with the text "Will be presented in the lecture") via the `environ` package.
That's all working well. However I'm using many equations and I'm also numbering them, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\renewenvironment{proof}{\noindent\textbf{Beweis.}\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\\}
\newenvironment{hiddenproof}{\noindent\textbf{Beweis.}\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\\}

\newif\ifhideproofs%
%\hideproofstrue%uncomment to hide proofs

\ifhideproofs%
  \usepackage{environ}
  \NewEnviron{hide}{\noindent\textbf{Beweis.}\hspace*{1em} In der Vorlesung.\hfill $\qed$\\[.5ex]}
  \let\hiddenproof\hide%
  \let\endhiddenproof\endhide%
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{hiddenproof}
  Some proof.
  \begin{equation}%
    \label{eq:eq1}
    Ax = b
  \end{equation}
\end{hiddenproof} 

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:eq2}
  Ax = c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

As the equation numbers are referenced in the lecture, I would like to keep them the same - No matter the proofs are visible or hidden.
When the `hiddenproof` is **not** hidden, everything's fine: `eq:eq1` will be labeled with `(1)` and `eq:eq2` will be labeled with `(2)`. However if I hide the proofs (by uncommenting `\hideproofstrue`), the first `equation` environment doesn't even exist anymore, and the second equation will get the label `(1)`.

Is there any way to "count" all the `equation` environments (and `align` and `gather`) and increment the equation counter accordingly? Or maybe there's another way to hide some of the proofs so that the `equation` environments are not removed but rather made invisible.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Without knowing how `hiddenproof` is defined, or what theorem package you're using, any attempt to answer this question is going to be pure speculation.  Please add the needed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could input the contents of the environment into a box that is never used. So every macro inside the environment is expanded (including counters) but never printed:

```
\ifhideproofs%
  \usepackage{environ}%
  \NewEnviron{hide}{\noindent\textbf{Beweis.}\hspace*{1em} In der Vorlesung.\hfill $\qed$\\[.5ex]%
    \setbox0\vbox{\BODY}% execute env without printing anything
  }
  \let\hiddenproof\hide%
  \let\endhiddenproof\endhide%
\fi
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you